# Sawtooth Configuring POET-Engine Log file

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I have issue in configuring the POET Engine to pickup the /etc/sawtooth/poet_engine_log_config.toml file.

Has anyone tried to change the logging format of the SAWTOOTH POET Engine on Ubuntu?

The sawtooth documentation [Log Configuration](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/sysadmin_guide/log_configuration.html) describes the logs can be configured in the /etc/sawtooth/ but even if I create the log file POET seems to ignore this file. Rest of all the services pickup the respective files e.g. intkey, rest_api, validator etc.

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that the file name is this **poet-engine-log-config.toml** and not poet_engine_log_config.toml.

[Looked at the code line 83](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-poet/blob/master/engine/sawtooth_poet_engine/main.py)